# Zero padding in oracle to_char

Tags: oracle

Given

```
to_char(myVariable, '00')
```

I get the following behaviour:

```
1 -> 01
10 -> 10
100 -> ###
```

How can I pad single-digit number with 0 but still able to display 100 as well?
This is what I want to obtain:

```
1 -> 01
10 -> 10
100 -> 100
```

Comment: Can you have negative and/or non integer values? If so, how to display them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(1,'FM900'),to_char(10,'FM900'),to_char(100,'FM900'),to_char(100,'FM900'),to_char(1000,'FM900')   from dual;
```

If you need longer numbers add more 9

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a `CASE` expression which conditionally pads single digits:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN myVariable < 10
         THEN TO_CHAR(myVariable, '00')
         ELSE TO_CHAR(myVariable) END AS output
FROM yourTable
```